# grails3 form body not read for PUT method

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, put, grails-3.0

I have a controller

```
def SampleController {
    def action(Domain d) {
        println params.state
    ....
```

in client side I do a jQuery ajax call with PUT method

```
$.ajax({url: '/sample/action/1', method: 'PUT', data: {'state':'APPROVED'}})
```

I get a `null`

Same thing this time with POST

```
$.ajax({url: '/sample/action/1', method: 'POST', data: {'state':'APPROVED'}})
```

I get `APPROVED`

In both cases I check request headers Content type is

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Can't a PUT request have a body ? or am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

`params` gives you reference to parameters passed in a Get request. To get the body of put/post use `request.JSON`.  In fact, you should be getting null in both examples.